# In Delphi, How can I change the color of grid lines in a TDBGrid?

Tags: delphi, colors, dbgrid

I am using a TDBGrid component in a Delphi application, when I change rows colors the grid lines became unclear or almost invisible.

So, can any one show us how to change the color of the grid lines?

I mean: how to change the color of cells borders(see next picture)

The cells borders

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the cell borders?  Font color?  Background color?

Comment: I mean cells borders

Comment: Please post your code and edit your question to be more specific about what exactly your trying to do.

Comment: JohnEasley , see the picture it could help you to understand my question

Comment: Why the downvotes? The expression "color of grid lines" is perfectly clear

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  Not sure about that, some would write 'lines' when they actually mean 'rows'.  Not my dv, btw, but I'm not sure the q merits the upvotes either.

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: @MartynA Delphi itself says grid lines in the meaning intended here, and rows for ... well rows. E.g. property `grid line width`. So I guess one could assume "official" terminology as default, at least before downvoting

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  Fair enough, I wasn't meaning to argue.

Comment: @MartynA Me neither. HNY btw.

Comment: @MartynA , I am using Delphi 10.2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you looking for

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const [Ref] Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
Var
  R: TRect;
begin
  R:= Rect;
  with DBGrid1.Canvas do
    begin
      Brush.Color:= clRed;
      R.Offset(Column.Width, 0);
      FillRect(R);
      R:= System.Types.Rect(Rect.Left, Rect.Bottom - 1, Rect.Right, Rect.Bottom);
      FillRect(R);
    end;
end;
```

The results will be like:

[image]

A better way (from [Tom Brunberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2292722/tom-brunberg) comment) is to use `FrameRect()` as

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const [Ref] Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  with DBGrid1.Canvas do
    begin
      Brush.Color:= clRed;
      FrameRect(Rect);
    end;
end;
```

Use [FrameRect()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-framerect) to draw a 1 pixel wide border around a rectangular region, which does not fill the interior of the rectangle with the Brush pattern. 
To draw a boundary using the Pen instead, use the [Polygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-polygon) method

Comment: Instead of twice `FillRect()` I would prefer `FrameRect()` or `Polygon()`