# How to remove DBGrid borders between rows

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to remove the row lines borders on the DBGrid. There is no property to change the DBGrid color directly, or to remove them. I tried, on the CustomDrawEvent, setting the canvas pen to psClear, but it did not work. I changed some properties in my DBGrid to make it look as the image below, like so:

```
Ctl3D: false
BorderStyle: bsSingle
DrawingStyle: gdsGradient
```

[image: I want to remove these white borders]

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53981784/in-delphi-how-can-i-change-the-color-of-grid-lines-in-a-tdbgrid) to remove the lines by using the sabe color as the background, but the result was not what I wanted and ended up like this (I used red to represent the wrong result):

[image]

I am trying to achieve something like this (Notice how there is no line between the rows):
[image]

Is there a way so I can remove these lines between the rows?

Edit: You can remove the columns and rows lines completely using

```
DBGrid.Options.dbColLines = false
DBGrid.Options.dbRowLines = false
```

Comment: DBGrid.Options.dgRowLines = False

Comment: And DBGrid.Options.dgColLines := False;

Comment: Thatnks for the replies. That gets me very close from the result I want. But what about the grid color? Is there a way to change it? I Know I can use the Rect solution as in the linked post, but is there a easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these to remove the gridlines

```
DBGrid.Options.dbColLines := false;
DBGrid.Options.dbRowLines := false;
```

When you use the Jedi Vcl you can just use the `TJvDBGRid` and it’s event `OnGetCellParams` to change the cell colors by setting the value of the `Background` parameter.

Else you should use the `OnDrawCell` event to draw the text yourself using your own background color.

Or you can use the `OnDrawColumnCell` event.

Comment: I can't find the event OnGetCellParams on the TDBGrid on Delphi XE 10.2. The code to removed, as I put in the Edit of my question, worked

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad. I’ve using using the Jedi VCL TJvDBGrid for so long, I just gave this answer...